# Material-UI Theme Override Issue

Tags: reactjs, styles, themes, material-ui

I am overriding the `<ExpansionPanelSummary/>` component in Material UI to have less margin.  I am using a theme with overrides to do this.

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiExpansionPanelSummary: {
      expanded: {
          marginTop: 5,
          marginBottom: 5,
      },
      content: {
        marginTop: 5,
        marginBottom: 5,
      },
    }
  },
```

The problem I run into however is that in the Material-UI built in css,  there are two classes being applied at the same time: **content** and **expanded**.

```
.MuiExpansionPanelSummary-content-567.MuiExpansionPanelSummary-expanded-564 {
  margin: 20px 0;
}
```

How can I override multiple applied classes?  Is it possible to create a theme rule for this?

Comment: Ok I have a workaround but it still doesn't completely answer my question.  Rather than using the number 5 as the override, I can use "5px !important"  however this still doesn't create a rule for when two classes are used.

Answer (score 1):

Got this working today. The margin you want is on the `expanded` class on content, so the rules need to look like this to get higher CSS specificity. Look for `'&.expanded'`.

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  expansionPanelSummaryContent: {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    '&.expanded': {
      margin: 0,
      backgroundColor: 'yellow',
    },
  },
}));

export default function MyComponent(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <ExpansionPanel expanded={props.expanded}>
      <ExpansionPanelSummary
        classes={{
          content: classes.expansionPanelSummaryContent,
          expanded: 'expanded'
        }}
      >
        ...
      </ExpansionPanelSummary>
    </ExpansionPanel>
  );
}
```